# returning an array from a .jsx file to be

Tags: reactjs

I have a file that holds an array of objects, I want to export that array and import it elsewhere to be used in a different part of the code. my problem is i cannot get it to return the data to a variable inside the file i want to use it in. for instance i have:
`const array = () => { return ([ {object1},{object2})}`
of which I am exporting the return, in my next file, i want to set that data equal to a new variable to hold it so i can map over the data and potentially render some card components for the screen. but when i do this `const objects = '../../path/path'`  it just sets it equal to that string, ive also tried just importing it `import objects from 'path'` ive tried destructure importing. I need to be able to use the data, and yes, its important to keep the data in a seperate file to keep the lengthy code smell down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, i was using a lambda function in my data export like: `export const data = () => {[{}]}` when i should have just set it to a variable like this: `export const data = [{},{}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use useContext and solve the problem easily, [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs-usecontext-hook#:~:text=%20ReactJS%20%E2%80%93%20useContext%20hook%20%201%20Syntax.,result.%20Published%20on%2019-Mar-2021%2015%3A14%3A40%20%20More%20](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs-usecontext-hook#:%7E:text=%20ReactJS%20%E2%80%93%20useContext%20hook%20%201%20Syntax.,result.%20Published%20on%2019-Mar-2021%2015%3A14%3A40%20%20More%20)

Comment: Im not sure what this will do, if i console log the variable that i assigned with useContext it just returns `undefined` i need the array, am i missing something? `const array = useContext(Variable)` where Variable is the import statement from that file. i.e. `import Variable from 'path'`

Comment: I figured it out, i was using a lambda function in my data export like: `export const data = () => {[{}]}` when i should have just set it to a variable like this: `export const data = [{},{}]`